# Django : Object didn't load in HTML template

Tags: python, django

I'm making my Django website and I'm getting an issue according to my first website template (my homepage).

#### Environment :

- Django 2.0.1
- Python 3.5
- MariaDB 10.1

#### Issue :

When I can access to my Django Homepage, it should display an image, according to my view but I get nothing. I get my picture only if I go somewhere else and I come back to the homepage.

#### My code :

My models.py

```
class Photo(models.Model) :

    Nom                 = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name="Nom de l'objet", blank=False)
    Date                = models.DateField()
    ...
    Image_upload        = models.ImageField(upload_to='Media/', width_field=None, height_field=None, verbose_name="Image")
```

My views.py :

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from Photographies.models import Photo


def Accueil(request):
    photo = Photo.objects.all().order_by('-Date')[0]

    return render(request, 'Accueil.html', {"photo": photo})
```

My HTML template :

```
<!--  This script lets to define homepage template for "Accueil" -->

{% extends 'Base_Accueil.html' %}

{% load staticfiles %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}

        <div id="content">

            <br></br>

            <div id="content-1">

               <div id="presentation-title">
                    <p>Petit mot de l'Astrophotographe & Développeur du site</p>
               </div>
               <div id="presentation-text">
                    <p>  Je vous souhaite la bienvenue sur mon site dédié à l'Astrophotographie. A travers votre parcours sur celui-ci, vous allez découvrir ma passion pour la photographie des objets de l'Univers. Du Soleil, notre étoile, aux galaxies les plus lointaines en passant par les vastes amas de gaz qui composent l'infiniment grand, vous allez pouvoir contempler des objets atypiques de part leurs formes et leurs couleurs.</p><br />

                    <p> C'est avec plaisir que je vous invite à vous ballader sur mon site, découvrir ma galerie d'images, mes bricolages, mes articles & publications, ... Vous trouverez également le matériel astronomique employé pour la réalisation des différents clichés disponibles sur ce site ainsi que diverses informations complémentaires. N'hésitez pas à partager vos avis et à venir le visiter régulièrement pour entrevoir les nouvelles images astrophotographiques.</p><br />

                    <p align="center">Je vous souhaite une bonne visite !</p>   
               </div> 
            </div>

            <br></br>

            <div class="row">
            </div>

            <div id="content-2">
                <div id="presentation-image-récente">
                    <p>Dernière image publiée</p>
                </div>
                <div id="presentation-image">
                        <li class="image">
                            <img src='{{photo.Image_upload.url}}'/>
                            <p></p> 
                            <figcaption>
                            <div>
                                <center>
                                <p></p>
                                <p><b>{{photo.Nom}} ({{photo.Designation}})</b></p>


                                </center>
                            </div>
                            </figcaption>
                        </li>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
            </div>
            <br></br>

        </div>
        <p></p>

{% endblock content %}
```

And finally my urls.py file :

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^Accueil$', views.Accueil, name='Accueil'),
]
```

My global urls.py file looks like :

```
import os
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name=os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'Accueil/templates/Accueil.html')), name='accueil'),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^Accueil/', include('Accueil.urls')),
    url(r'^Materiel/', include('Materiel.urls')),
    url(r'^Photographies/', include('Photographies.urls')),
    url(r'^Articles/', include('Articles.urls')),
    url(r'^Meteo/', include('Meteo.urls')),
    url(r'^Presentation/', include('Presentation.urls')),
    url(r'^Contact/', include('Contact.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I suspect an issue according to this line :

```
url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name=os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'Accueil/templates/Accueil.html')), name='accueil'),
```

Because the url is just : http://localhost:8000
And if I write http://localhost:8000/Accueil/Accueil, it is the same template (my homepage) but with my loaded picture.

Comment: There are plenty of things wrong here but I can't understand why you would think this would work. Your first pattern does not call a view at all so how would `photo` be passed to that template?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Sorry if I learned Django by myself just with some stack questions and network lessons/tutorials. I will try to change my first pattern.

Comment: @BugHunter I'm not sure because I select just the last one. I think this issue (as say @DanielRoseman) comes from my urls.py file

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution to my mind :

I change my views.py file :

```
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from Photographies.models import Photo


class AccueilTemplateView(TemplateView):

    template_name = "Accueil.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['photo'] = Photo.objects.all().order_by('-Date')[0]

        return context
```

Then, in my global urls.py file :

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

from Accueil.views import AccueilTemplateView


urlpatterns = [
    path(r'', AccueilTemplateView.as_view(), name='accueil'),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^Accueil/', include('Accueil.urls')),
    url(r'^Materiel/', include('Materiel.urls')),
    url(r'^Photographies/', include('Photographies.urls')),
    url(r'^Articles/', include('Articles.urls')),
    url(r'^Meteo/', include('Meteo.urls')),
    url(r'^Presentation/', include('Presentation.urls')),
    url(r'^Contact/', include('Contact.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

And finally in my urls.py file according to Accueil App :

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from .views import AccueilTemplateView


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^Accueil$', AccueilTemplateView.as_view(), name='Accueil'),
]
```

Comment: the problem indeed with your urlpattern. You are using `TemplateView` for root path. And even it using correct template, it's not passing any template context. So you cannot see any image details on the main page. In your fix you are using view and pass context inside it to the view, so images rendering correctly in this case. P.S. BTW nice second movie:)

Comment: @neverwalkaloner Ok thank you for your very good explanation ! I understand my mistake and that's why I found how I can solve it. Some things are again pretty obscur, unclear because learn programmation alone is not easy ;) but Stackoverflow let each one to be better ! Learn about each personnal issues. PS : Oh thank you, do you want a n°3 ? :P